# Writing spatial file to Oracle database using R?

Tags: r, oracle, spatial

I'm trying to write a spatial file to an Oracle database using R, but I keep getting an error. The error message doesn't provide much information, so I'm not clear what the issue is. I'm not even too sure if this is possible. However, I am able to create an empty table in the database with a SDO_GEOMETRY field type using sqlDeveloper, so it seems like it is possible.

Sample code of what I have tried:

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(tigris)

    sf_state <- states(year = 2021, cb = FALSE)
    
    dbWriteTable(conn        = db_conn,
                 value       = sf_state,
                 name        = "TEST_TABLE",
                 field.types = c(geometry = "SDO_GEOMETRY"))
```